# Weird behavior of PHP

Tags: php

according to :

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > var_dump("0" != 0); 
bool(false)
php > var_dump(0 != null);
bool(false)
php > var_dump("0" != null);
bool(true)
```

can you explain why the last assertion is true ?

By the way, it is PHP cli 5.3.6.

Comment: What is **weird** here? Are you using PHP first time?

Comment: Because PHP's type-system has been designed to irritate everybody that uses it: http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php.

Comment: If you think normally, this would wrack up your mathematical induction. @Lion, did you ever do math in your life?

Comment: Which kind of **math** are you talking about. This is the kind of question where you begin learning the subject (PHP).

Comment: Keil, there's no use trying to prove anything about PHP. The language is not based on mathematical theorems or sound computer science. It's a hack by Rasmus Lerdorf, a man noted for saying stuff like "I'm not a real programmer. I throw together things until it works then I move on".  Don't expect anything beautiful from the PHP type system.

Comment: I should add that I have nothing against Lerdorf. I understand what he and the PHP devs are trying to do. I have even used PHP for nine years! But understand that they take a *very* pragmatic approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is defined in the manual page [PHP type comparison tables](http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php).

I find some of these very unintuitive. `"0" == false` is for example retarded since you often may have a form where the user inputs the number `0`. Now you need to check if a field is set using [isset](http://php.net/isset) instead of just doing a `if($field)`. Also note that `empty("0") == true`!

That's why I use `===` to get type-checked comparisons or use a language without automatic type casts.

Answer (score 5):

Because it is a string with a value 0, it's not empty like you think (contains "0")

Comment: Agreed, I was just specifiying the null value ;)

Answer (score 3):

`"0"` is not a null.  It's a string.

`""` isn't null either.  That's an empty string.

Comment: if you are doing loose comparison, which you often do.

Comment: `"" == null` but not `"" === null`

Answer (score 3):

It's not weird, [it's documented](http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php)

Answer (score 1):

"0" and 0 aren't nulls.
"0" is a string.
0 is an integer.
 A null is no value.

Comment: php > var_dump(0 != null);
bool(false)

Answer (score 1):

```
$ php -a
<?php
var_dump("config~123~123" == true);
bool(true)
var_dump("config~123~123" == 0);
bool(true)
```

same, so logic !